# Glassfish startup error leading to app showing 503 error

Tags: java, glassfish

I have an app deployed in Glassfishv2 that was working fine all along. When I redeployed it with the latest code, it is giving me a 503 error. With the log saying error congifuring app listener, skipped installing app listeners due to previous errors, startup of context /app_name failed due to prev errors.

There can't be problem with the war folder because I've taken a war folder that is deployed and working in the company server(errors in my local).

Lately, I've noticed that my glassfish startup starts with these errors:

```
SEVERE: MSG_ErrorReadingConfig
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.config.beans.Updatecenter.read(Updatecenter.java:668)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.config.beans.Updatecenter.read(Updatecenter.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.config.ConfigManagerImpl.initializeUpdatecenterBean(ConfigManagerImpl.java:414)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.config.ConfigManagerImpl.<init>(ConfigManagerImpl.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.UpdateManager.getConfigManager(UpdateManager.java:173)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.schedule.SchedulerImpl.<init>(SchedulerImpl.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.enterprise.update.UpdateManager.getScheduler(UpdateManager.java:234)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.cli.commands.StartDomainCommand$UpdateCenter.run(StartDomainCommand.java:726)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am thinking this is the cause for that application giving a 503 error. But at the same time other apps seem to be working normally(which is the reason I overlooked this startup problem for a long time).I am not sure what to do for the above stacktrace.

Has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if there is an XML syntax error in one of your webapp's configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

We observed the same issue on our setup. We had applied a security patch from Oracle recently but not sure if that was causing it. We did a reinstall of whole cluster and the error was gone. Hope this helps.